# “hashchange” doesn't fire in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hashchange

Hi I am building this website: http://www.freiheitmedia.com/en/. It is build with the Themify Ultra theme.

**My goal is to get rid of the #something part in the url when scrolling or clicking on a link.**

I need to do it with JavaScript/jQuery because there is no theme based solution and the support staff can't help me.

I already tested and know that the following code replaces the url as I want:

```
history.replaceState("",document.title,window.location.pathname + window.location.search);
```

Now, the problem is that **I seemingly can't get the "hashchange" event to fire.** I am putting the following code in the footer and the alert statement is not reached in both cases:

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e){
        alert("hiii");
    });
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
    window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(e){
        alert("hiii");
    }, false);
</script>
```

I suspect that the hashchange event might be prevented by the theme's settings but it's just a guess.

**Do you guys have any idea why "hashchange" is not firing?**

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you're asking. Are you expecting to see a `hashchange` event when you run the code in your first code block? (You won't, `hashchange` isn't fired by `history.replaceState`.) Or are you trying to respond to hash changes by triggering the code in your first block?

Comment: FWIW, your code to hook the event (second and third blocks) is correct (for a standards-compliant browser -- so, not IE8 or earlier, and not IE9+ if they're in "compatibility mode").

Comment: @tjcrowder when you visit the site, and scroll down, you will see that the url changes depending what section you are in. Specifically the #part changes. My goal was to prevent this behavior and have a clean url (without any #hashes) all the time. So I tried to access this behavior by listening to the "hashchange" event. But for some reason the "hashchange" event is not triggering when the url changes it's #part. Is this understandable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your clarifying comment:

> when you visit the site, and scroll down, you will see that the url changes depending what section you are in. Specifically the #part changes. My goal was to prevent this behavior and have a clean url (without any #hashes) all the time.

The best way to do that would be to find the plugin that's responding to scroll events by updating the hash (which is meant to be helpful, presumably; taking you back to that part of the page if you bookmark it) and turn it off. Fighting for control of the hash with a plugin on the page is a bad idea.

Very much second-best to that:

Since `hashchange` isn't firing, the plugin must be using `history`'s `replaceState` or `pushState` or similar to set the hash, as that doesn't fire `hashchange`. You could replace those functions with your own version that strips the hash fragment:

```
// I DON'T RECOMMEND THIS APPROACH
(function() {
    function removeHash(url) {
        var u = String(url || "");
        var x = u.lastIndexOf("#");
        return x == -1 ? u : u.substring(0, x);
    }
    var originalReplaceState = history.replaceState;
    history.replaceState = function(state, title, url) {
        url = removeHash(url);
        return originalReplaceState.call(history, state, title, url);
    };
    var originalPushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state, title, url) {
        url = removeHash(url);
        return originalPushState.call(history, state, title, url);
    };
})();
```

Again, though, really it's best to find whatever is responding to the scroll event by adding hash fragments and disable it.

Comment: @tjcrowder Thank you for your response and taking your time! :) The above (not recommended) code works in my case. I would like to know though what you mean exactly by your first approach. What do you mean by "find whatever is responding to the scroll event by adding hash fragments and disable it."? How do I "add hash fragments"? Would be nice if you can elaborate on that, I want to learn :)

Comment: @StanislawLorenz: Glad that helps. The hash changing as you scroll is not standard behavior. So there's JavaScript code on that page (a plugin or whatever) that is doing that. So rather than fight with it, I suggest finding it and turning it off, since you don't want the behavior it adds.